# Filling Excel ranges with worksheetfunction result using vba address

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to phrase the question exactly, so I'll let the code do the talking to start!

```
lROW = 10 ' 
Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lROW).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(1, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(1, 3).Address & ")"
```

This inputs a formula from A1 down to A10 with the correct rows (`=SUM(B1:C1)`)

I can then convert this to value using `Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lROW).value2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lROW).value2`

Is there anyway I can skip a step by directly using worksheetfunction? I know I can do this with certain range addresses but it's not working with e.g.:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lROW).Value2 = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 2).Address(False, True) & ":" & Cells(1, 3).Address(False, True)))
```

I'm just getting row 1 answers in every row for col A

Even though I'm using the address parameters (false, true) to signify no absolute referencing on the row... is there a way to do this in one fell swoop?

Comment: Write your own function in VBA. You will get what you want.

Comment: Remove the address part. Refer to just the range itself.

Comment: And you will need to loop through the range and do the sum on each row.  It would be faster to use memory arrays than to iterate the worksheet.  Second fastest is to do what you already are doing.  the slowest is to iterate the worksheet range.

Comment: Removing the `.address` doesn't work - causes an error. I'm definitely trying to avoid loops on a worksheet with 10k + rows. I figured since I can fill the formula by chopping up the string with the address I could use the same addresses within a worksheetfunction version of the formula. Maybe not though.

Comment: @ScottCraner - can you do it with Evaluate in one go? I can't work out the syntax if it is possible.

Comment: helpME1986 that's great thanks for all the help very useful much thanks

Comment: @SJR nothing is coming to me on how to do that without looping.  using arrays will be the quickest.

Comment: I just tried several versions of [] eval but it's not working for me. Since I wrote the code for "=SUM" then .value = .value already I'll stick with that instead of trying to push stuff in to arrays. Not even sure where to start with that tbh!

Answer (score 3):

This ought to do it:

```
Dim ar As Variant
Dim rg As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1:C10")

ar = rg.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
    ar(i, 1) = ar(i, 2) + ar(i, 3)
Next

rg.Columns(1).Value = ar
```

---

**EDIT**

I've had a different idea based on the questioner's method. How about this short and sweet one - no loop required:

```
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
rg.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC[1]:RC[2])"
rg.Value = rg.Value
```

Or even...

```
With Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC[1]:RC[2])"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Ah, well the reason I'm using SUM is because the last column could actually be 50 + away so `ar(i,2) + ar(i,3) + ...` might not be the best - the edit to your question looks very neat! Like it.

Comment: In that case, yes, the edit version would be best with something like `rg.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC[1]:RC[50])"`

Answer (score 2):

Example of using arrays.

```
Sub try()
Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
Dim inArr As Variant
Dim oArr() As Variant
With Sheet1

    lrow = 10
    inArr = .Range("B1:C" & lrow).Value
    ReDim oArr(1 To UBound(inArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(inArr, 1) To UBound(inArr, 1)
        oArr(i, 1) = Application.Sum(Application.Index(inArr, i, 0))
    Next i
    .Range("A1:A" & lrow).Value = oArr

End With

End Sub
```